# In a Java card game, how would I pause briefly after every card is dealt to a hand?

Tags: java, user-interface, sleep, wait

I'm creating a blackJack game in java using swing in netbeans. Cards are dealt out sequentially to a player's multiple hands and the dealer. JLabels with Card images are to jLayerdPanes when each card is dealt. I want to pause briefly after each card is dealt. Currently you just see them all being dealt at once. This is the code for the first four cards being dealt out.

```
    if(hand1.handIsInPlay()==true){
       dealCard(jLPaneHand1,hand1);
       pause();
    }
    if(hand2.handIsInPlay()==true){
       dealCard(jLPaneHand2,hand2);
       pause();
    }
    if(hand3.handIsInPlay()==true){
       dealCard(jLPaneHand3,hand3);
       pause();
    }
    dealCard(jLPaneDealerHand,dealerHand);
```

And here is the pause method I tried:

```
public void pause(){
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Here is a second pause method I tried:

```
public void pause(){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

Neither worked as intended. What looks to have happened was that if three hands were in play, then the program summed up 3x1000ms and waited for that length and then dealt all the cards at once.

How can I make the program pause after every card is dealt?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that Thread.sleep is called in current thread. In Java with Swing there will be usually at least 2 threads - Main thread and Swing thread - when you trigger an action appropriate listener is called and it's method executed - as long as this method is still run it cannot move on to other tasks like. e.g. redrawing the cards.

So basically you need to move this pause action to some other thread that will order action of drawing a card with e.g. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, then wait for some time, then again order redrawing and so on.

Basically you need to make sure that GUI thread is not blocked and can work all the time, and orders comes from some other thread(s) - and they CAN sleep without bothering the user.

In your case all happens in 1 thread so when you call on sleep GUI thread sleeps and cannot perform any actions like drawing what you wanted it to draw - it patiently waits till you code in Swing thread stops its execution.

EDIT:

Quick example - knowing exact requirements and code would make it act better...

in listener call e.g.:

```
new Thread(new CardDealing()).start(); // delegates task to the new thread
```

while the task would look like:

```
public CardDealing extends Runnable {
    // inner data, methods and so on

    public void run() {
        if(hand1.handIsInPlay()==true){
            dealCard(jLPaneHand1,hand1);
            pause();
        }
        if(hand2.handIsInPlay()==true){
            dealCard(jLPaneHand2,hand2);
            pause();
        }
        if(hand3.handIsInPlay()==true){
            dealCard(jLPaneHand3,hand3);
            pause();
        }
        dealCard(jLPaneDealerHand,dealerHand);
    }

    public void dealCards(...) {
         // this part will be run in a non-gui thread - make sure that
         // all calculations and changes in model are made here
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 // this will be run in a swing thread
                 // - make sure that only code dealing directly
                 // with GUI is called here
                 guiDealCards(jPane,hand);
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Of course depending on your requirements `CardDealing` class might take parameters, contains references to some data and so on - but that's a matter of overall design. Communiction between GUI and working thread should work more or less like this. You might also try `invokeAndWait` in this particular case - just make sure that `pause()` is NOT called inside GUI thread (custom Swing components, `Runnables` that you delegate, `paint` methods etc).

EDIT 2:

You might find [this link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073477/swing-gui-programming/customize-swingworker-to-improve-swing-guis.html) helpful - it would help you understanding how Swing works, and why you should divide your logic into at least 2 parts: GUI and non-GUI. Then whatever 
isn't related to GUI place directly in `dealCards` method, while all GUI related stuff in `guiDealCards` - I don't know what exactly you are doing there so I cannot you that for you.

Comment: How do I move this pause action to some other thread that will order the action of drawing the card with SwingUtilities.invokeLater? What would the code look like?

Comment: This is short example. I cannot really write more since it all depends on how would you use it. But basically that's how it works - you delegate things to and from to make sure that some actions are always executed inside GUI thread and some are never done there. Try to use debugger in Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ - you'll see in which thread you stop at each line - it would help you understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm trying to digest this but where does the pausing happen? and what is the guiDealCards method supposed to achieve?

Comment: Ok, lets start with how GUI works - you have 1 thread waiting for any kind of action - clicking, resizing window, key pressing and so on. On any of those event it searches for a component that makes use of that action (has focus) and calls its event listener to perform the response to event. In the very same thread are performed all updates of how GUI looks - so if you call `sleep(1000);` it will be executed in the same thread that draws and listens to events - so GUI looks like frozen for a while, then performs all queued actions.

Comment: What I wrote is just a sketch showing how would you split your logic so that all logic not directly related to GUI would be executed in another thread - this way it won't look like looked, and whatever you draw will be shown immediately not after all your processing logic has ended. I don't know what your `dealCards` method do but basically anything that operates on Swing components can be extracted into another method (`guiDrawCards`).